# How to overlay a figure using Greasemonkey (or Tampermonkey)?

Tags: javascript, overlay, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

How do I draw a circle on a specific position over a website using Greasemonkey?

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         test
// @match        stackoverflow.com/

var canv = document.createElement('canvas');
canv.id = 'someId';

var c=document.getElementById("someId");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100,75,50,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: You need to add the canvas element into the page e.g. [Add canvas to a page with javascript](//stackoverflow.com/a/9152303)

Comment: @wOxxOm , I added the canvas element, as shown in the question,but it didnt work.

Comment: You didn't add it, which is why I've linked the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **immediate problem** with that code is that nowhere was something like `.appendChild(canv)` used to **actually add it to the page**.

---

But if you really want to **overlay a figure** on some 3rd-party website, you need more than that.
You need to:

1. Get a handle to the target "figure" (image or other node).
2. Create a canvas of the same size and add it to the page.
3. Use CSS to position over the target node(s) from step 1.  To make this part easier, I suggest wrapping the target node(s) in a `<div>` or `<span>`. See below.
4. Draw to the canvas as desired.

For example, suppose the target webpage has some kawaii picture that you must markup:
      [image: It's ADORABLE!]

Here's one way with this ***complete script***:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Overlay the only image
// @match    *://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// @grant    GM.listValues 
// ==/UserScript==
//- The @grant directives are needed to restore the proper sandbox.

var jImg    = $("img");
/*-- Contain the image in a position-relative element so that the canvas can use
    absolute positioning to fly over it.
*/
jImg.wrap (
    $("<span>", {id:"gmWrpSpn", style: "display: inline-block; position: relative;"} )
);
var targW = jImg[0].width,  targH = jImg[0].height;
var jCanvas = $(`<canvas width=${targW} height=${targH}>`).css ( {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    left: 0
} ).insertAfter (jImg);
var cCntxt          = jCanvas[0].getContext ("2d");
cCntxt.lineWidth    = 7;
cCntxt.strokeStyle  = '#FF8300';
cCntxt.beginPath ();
cCntxt.moveTo ( 30, 170);
cCntxt.lineTo (100,  30);
cCntxt.lineTo (170, 170);
cCntxt.closePath ();
cCntxt.stroke ();
cCntxt.beginPath ();
cCntxt.moveTo (100,  30);
cCntxt.lineTo (100, 170);
cCntxt.stroke ();
cCntxt.beginPath ();
cCntxt.arc (100.5, 127.5855, 42.4145, 0, 2*Math.PI);
cCntxt.stroke ();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem Ipsum <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/itbfI.jpg"></p>
```

Run the code snippet to see the script in action.